# how do you pronounce centos?

Tags: linux, centos

What is the correct way to pronounce centos? I say centos as in sent-oh-ess. I hear other people say sent-ohss.

Comment: According to the CentOS forum admin, the CentOS founder Lance Davis pronounces it "sent oss". Another common pronunciation is "sent oh ess" https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=693#p4602

Comment: I don't see why this is off-topic. We need to know how to pronounce names we use.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is primarily up to you, since this question has [not been definitely answered before](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2005-May/thread.html#4535):

Quoting this [forum post](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&topic_id=7358&forum=18):

> hehehe ... it remembers me the old
>   sound card test when you heard Linus
>   saying 'hello, this is Linus Torvalds
>   and i pronounce linux as linux ...'
>   ...    Let me just say that the
>   pronounciation is up to you ... even
>   CentOS developers pronounce it one
>   time Saintoss and Saint-O-S next time
>   ... Because of the capitals letters i
>   pronounce it Saint-O-S ...

and

> Capitalisation make no difference to
>   pronunciation, so if you wanted "Sent
>   Oh Ess" or "Kent Oh Ess" you would
>   need to spell it Cent O S. While
>   Americans can get away with "Scent
>   Arse" among themselves it would be
>   inadvisable to use this expression
>   elsewhere if you wanted to be taken
>   seriously. I have been automatically
>   pronouncing it "Sentoss", as it looks
>   Greek and I always get the "C" wrong -
>   if it were Greek it should (I think)
>   be "Kentoss".  "Cent" as a prefix has
>   at least 2 meanings, the number 100
>   and the root of Centre, my Shorter
>   Oxford has columns full of words
>   derived from them. I think it is a
>   good name, it has a classical
>   grandeur, it is short, it is not
>   likely to be confused with anything
>   else, and there will be relatively few
>   variant pronounciations outside of
>   local dialect differences.  But who
>   cares how you say it if it boots?

**Personally, I pronounce it *Cent-O-S*.** How you pronounce it is up to you: people will understand what distribution you mean regardless of the way you pronounce it (or, if not, it is probably time to see a speech therapist :))